# Why RGB value bigger than 1 when convert from spectrum in PBRT-V3

Tags: pbrt-v3

In PBRT-V3, the light has following spectrum in scene file(Note that the scene file is not come from PBRT itself):

```
"spectrum" [400.0 0.0 500.0 8.0 600.0 15.6 700.0 18.4]
```

then it's converted to following RGB in C++:

```
"rgb" [20.7467213 10.8233843 2.76458955]
```

is this correct? Why the RGB value exceeds 1? Whether this is used to indicate light intensity?

Comment: HDR lights or as you said it's basically color*intensity in a single rgb triple I guess

Comment: Color does not really jave a upper limit. What you see on screen is normalized for the screen device. But that does not mean a blue, brighter more intense blue does not exist. Just not what your monitor can show.